# Web Audio decodeAudioData iOS on chunked dash audio

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, web-audio-api

I'm looking into playing chunks of dash-audio (aac, 44100) through a sourceBufferNode.
First I get the index byte range buffer which has all the header information.
Second I get the chunk
Third I concatenate the two buffers
[It works!!!](https://rad.wtf/deriveur/decode-dash/) **but only on desktop**

On iOS where I'm interested in using this, I get the `null` error on the `decodeAudioData`

If anyone has any ideas why Safari iOS behaves differently / ideas to get this working I would love to know.

*EDIT:*

[Here is a repo for the code](https://github.com/samradical/dash-web-audio/)

Comment: show the code ... doing a view source shows some library not client calls to Web Audio API

Comment: Thanks for the interest Scott. [Here](https://github.com/samradical/dash-web-audio/) it is

Answer (score 0):

From the Safari Developer Library at Apple:

> **Note**: On iOS, the Web Audio API requires sounds to be triggered from an explicit user action, such as a tap. Calling noteOn() from an onload event will not play sound.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH6-SW5

Safari is a long way behind the actual Web Audio API standard unfortunately so it may not work in your way right now.

In reality, you need a touch event to trigger playback of each element, not to trigger requests to schedule playback. It is part of a drive to both save battery by not rendering anything until the user commands it.